# D3 Area fill with different color based on conditions

Tags: d3.js

[Please click here to see sample graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVLP5.png)

Hi,

i am working with Angular 8 and D3 version 4  graphs.

I have a case where i have to plot area with d3 with 3 different colors based on a  conditions of two different axes.

I tried 3 approaches
1.  Create 3 different areas  - but we are unable to find matching point of line and axis.
2.  Single area  with 3 different colors based on condition – conditional fill  is not working with area. And with linear gradients unable to predict stop offset.
3.  Color overlay  - but it not looks good and has some issue also.

In above graph we have two axes Min and Max.

3 Conditions are as below 
1.  Line above max area should be green.
2.  Between two axes it should be white.
3.  Below min it should be red .

Please help me if any one worked on such a scenario and has knowledge about this .

Thanks in advance

Comment: I had this requirement once this year, unfortunately I can not share the code. I solved this with distinct areas for each color.

Comment: Please post some code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Linear Gradients would work, as you could dynamically set the offsets in the code?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand you want to fill the regions based on a certain y-value.

With a `path` element **fill** attribute you can easily achieve the following :

[image: Image with different regions having different color using D3]

Some minimal code to achieve the above:

```
   // Add the line
    svg
        .append("path")
        .datum(cdata)
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
        .attr("d", d3.line()
            .x(function(d) { return x(d.key) })
            .y(function(d) { return y(d.value) })
        );


    // Add the green regions
    svg.append("path")
        .datum(cdata)
        .attr("fill", '#BFB')
        .attr("stroke", "none")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1)
        .attr("d", d3.area()
            .x(function(d,i) { return x(d.key) })
            .y0(function(d) { return y(0) })
            .y1(function(d) { if (d.value>0) {return y(d.value)}else{return y(0)} })
        );

    // Add the red regions
    svg.append("path")
        .datum(cdata)
        .attr("fill", '#FBB')
        .attr("stroke", "none")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1)
        .attr("d", d3.area()
            .x(function(d,i) { return x(d.key) })
            .y0(function(d) { return y(0) })
            .y1(function(d) { if (d.value<0) {return y(d.value)}else{return y(0)} })
        );
```